# install specific java version for 12.04

Tags: 12.04, java

I updated my 12.04 server with latest packages among them was an update to java 1.8u20.

Now I found out that my application is not running correctly with java 1.8u20. Now I looking for a way to downgrade Java to previous version or 1.8u5 in my case.

I tried to install a specific version

```
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer=8u5-1~webupd8~3
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer=8u5-1~webupd8
apt-get install oracle-java8-installer=8u5-1

E: Version 'XXX' for 'oracle-java8-installer' was not found
```

But the version I had from http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/webupd8_java?dist=saucy doesn't seem to work.

My Question is, how can I install a specific Version of java 8?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you need install specific version of Java on any distro, you must do it manually, but it is easy.

First you need which architecture OS you have.

```
uname -a
```

The x86_64 is 64bit and ix86 (x can be 3 or 6).

If you have 64 bit OS (in present it is probably) follow this steps. 
-> Open the terminal.

1) Create directory and go to /opt/jdk

```
mkdir /opt/jdk
cd /opt
```

2) Download Java package (if someone need another version only need change version and build in link)

```
wget --header "Cookie: oraclelicense=accept-securebackup-cookie" http://download.oracle.com/otn-pub/java/jdk/8u5-b13/jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

3) Optional (if you are not logged as root you need):

```
sudo su
```

4) Untar the package:

```
tar -zxf jdk-8u5-linux-x64.tar.gz -C /opt/jdk
```

5) Set Oracle's Java as default:

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/java 100
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /opt/jdk/jdk1.8.0_05/bin/javac 100
```

6) Check Java version if it os ok

```
java -version
```

I follow this part of this [tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-manually-install-oracle-java-on-a-debian-or-ubuntu-vps), but this method is for anyone distro. For example I mainly used [this](http://tecadmin.net/steps-to-install-java-on-centos-5-6-or-rhel-5-6/) for installation on servers where we nedd specific version of Java 7.

Comment: This was great, any chance of an edit for the UNDO of the update-alternatives ?

Comment: Unfortunately because of oracle's certifcate scheme if you do wget --https-only it fails since the file resolves to download.ubuntu.com and the cert is from akamai for akamai domains. 

I'd really perfer to use apt to install software in general. Is there really no way to get specific java 8 versions through apt?

Comment: Note you might still need to run `update-alternatives --config java` to point to the newer version.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the steps for the answer and it is *almost* perfect.

update-alternatives does not make sure you have any necessary dependencies- it is just an official way to track softlinks from system folders to main exectubles for things like java and javac.

On my light version of Ubuntu 18.04 I was missing some x libraries. I was able to add those to get the desired result:

```
sudo apt-get install -y libxext-dev libxrender-dev libxtst-dev
```

I was running a java application that uses AWT / Screen objects. I was getting a crash with a NullPointerException in Main. Not very informative, but I had seen the same problem when my $DISPLAY was not set correctly to an X system ready to accept the java draw commands. Adding the x libraries will give you a fuller range of capabilities for the java you install.